# Python WebDriver wait for page to load

Tags: python, webdriver

I am using a Chrome Driver, writing in Python, accessing pages that each require a login. After login I would like the program to wait for the entire page to load before taking a screenshot of the page. Can you help with this wait procedure?

Answer (score 2):

`driver.get(url)` already waits for the page to load.

You could use `selenium.webdriver.support.ui.WebDriverWait()` to explicitly wait for a condition.

ChromeDriver 18.0.995.0 doesn't support taking a page screenshot on Linux.

Comment: not sure why this answer has a negative score.  is it incorrect?